# Libreoffice on 16.04 - memory settings to prevent freezes?

Tags: libreoffice

Libreoffice 5.1.2.2 (Build 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1) on Ubuntu 16.04 is freezing for me a lot - just hangs, window shades until maybe 10 minutes later it unfreezes. This happens with Impress, Writer and Calc, for nearly empty, text only documents and larger (but not massive) documents alike. Playing with memory settings seems to help a bit. I'm wondering whether there are any optimal memory settings for Libreoffice, or even what exactly the memory settings actually mean.

Note that another PC running 14.04.3 with up to date Libreoffice also has this problem. I think it must be an older version though - I note that the maximum memory is limited to 256mb, whereas 5.1.2.2 does not seem to to have any limit on maximum value of memory. (nothing to do with physical memory - system running 5.1.2.2 has 8Gb of ram. Other system has 16Gb of RAM).

Comment: Did you upgrade either LibreOffice or Ubuntu on those machines, or fresh install?

Comment: I now use `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk libreoffice --calc`, for example, to launch LibreOffice in gtk2 mode. Seems less resource-intensive than the default gtk3 mode. Lubuntu 16.04 upgraded from 14.04, LibreOffice Version: 5.1.2.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu.

Comment: Jacob Vlijm - Fresh installs, and only updates as would have been pushed out through the official repos through the software updater.

Comment: I experience similar issue after moving up to version 5.1. Also the headless instance we use in our backend process to build and/or convert documents seems to be affected. After the upgrade the same process takes 15(!!!) minutes to build a 30-page long document.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/975945/80997

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uninstalling `libreoffice-gtk*` made a significant difference for me. The drawback is that the UI integration would go away.

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk*
```

It seems to be a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1577093

Comment: I added a bug report in the LO bugzilla: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104716

Comment: What's the "UI integration" that goes away?

Comment: @Dronz, the icons look like you are back in the 90's, plus some redrawing problems...

Answer (score 0):

Give libreoffice more dedicated space to work with. "Tools", "Options", "Memory", (use for libreoffice - increase to 1000mb (or whatever is more than you now have) Also change "remove from memory" to 5 minutes. Then go to "Load Save General" and make "Autosave" every three minutes. Ubuntu is cool. Libreoffice is cool. Enjoy!

Comment: This option no longer exists.