# LibreOffice 5.1 writer crashes after sporadically after highlighting

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, crash

Program and GUI crashes, and goes back to login screen after a while. Currently, two files from today in `/var/crash` one is 380 kB and the other is 33 MB. Time is different so seems to be related to two different crashes. Computer is Toshiba Z30 with Skylake video card. Already disabled Java runtime environment in options following some suggestions on other posts. Hard to pin point crash as it happens sporadically but screen freezes and there is always highlighted text on last screen.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Below is the beginning of the content of the one of the files in `/var/crash` (the remainder seems to be more of the same binary stuff from the core dump):

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
CurrentDesktop: Unity
Date: Mon Oct  2 15:29:12 2017
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 16.04
ExecutablePath: /sbin/upstart
ExecutableTimestamp: 1463667884
ProcCmdline: /sbin/upstart --user
ProcCwd: /home/adva
ProcEnviron:
 LC_PAPER=he_IL.UTF-8
 LC_ADDRESS=he_IL.UTF-8
 LC_MONETARY=he_IL.UTF-8
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 LC_NUMERIC=he_IL.UTF-8
 LC_TELEPHONE=he_IL.UTF-8
 PATH=(custom, user)
 LC_IDENTIFICATION=he_IL.UTF-8
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_MEASUREMENT=he_IL.UTF-8
 LANGUAGE=en_US
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 LC_TIME=he_IL.UTF-8
 LC_NAME=he_IL.UTF-8
ProcMaps:
 5601dbdbe000-5601dbe05000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 12976347                   /sbin/upstart
 5601dc005000-5601dc007000 r--p 00047000 08:02 12976347                   /sbin/upstart
 5601dc007000-5601dc008000 rw-p 00049000 08:02 12976347                   /sbin/upstart
 5601dc7f8000-5601dc8db000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
 7f14fac14000-7f14fac1f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606846                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
 7f14fac1f000-7f14fae1e000 ---p 0000b000 08:02 7606846                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
 7f14fae1e000-7f14fae1f000 r--p 0000a000 08:02 7606846                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
 7f14fae1f000-7f14fae20000 rw-p 0000b000 08:02 7606846                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
 7f14fae20000-7f14fae26000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fae26000-7f14fae31000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606856                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
 7f14fae31000-7f14fb030000 ---p 0000b000 08:02 7606856                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
 7f14fb030000-7f14fb031000 r--p 0000a000 08:02 7606856                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
 7f14fb031000-7f14fb032000 rw-p 0000b000 08:02 7606856                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
 7f14fb032000-7f14fb048000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606840                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
 7f14fb048000-7f14fb247000 ---p 00016000 08:02 7606840                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
 7f14fb247000-7f14fb248000 r--p 00015000 08:02 7606840                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
 7f14fb248000-7f14fb249000 rw-p 00016000 08:02 7606840                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
 7f14fb249000-7f14fb24b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fb24b000-7f14fb253000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606842                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
 7f14fb253000-7f14fb452000 ---p 00008000 08:02 7606842                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
 7f14fb452000-7f14fb453000 r--p 00007000 08:02 7606842                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
 7f14fb453000-7f14fb454000 rw-p 00008000 08:02 7606842                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
 7f14fb454000-7f14fbe14000 r--p 00000000 08:02 11803633                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
 7f14fbe14000-7f14fbe26000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606791                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
 7f14fbe26000-7f14fc026000 ---p 00012000 08:02 7606791                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
 7f14fc026000-7f14fc027000 r--p 00012000 08:02 7606791                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
 7f14fc027000-7f14fc028000 rw-p 00013000 08:02 7606791                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
 7f14fc028000-7f14fc02b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606771                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
 7f14fc02b000-7f14fc22a000 ---p 00003000 08:02 7606771                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
 7f14fc22a000-7f14fc22b000 r--p 00002000 08:02 7606771                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
 7f14fc22b000-7f14fc22c000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 7606771                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
 7f14fc22c000-7f14fc29a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606876                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
 7f14fc29a000-7f14fc49a000 ---p 0006e000 08:02 7606876                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
 7f14fc49a000-7f14fc49b000 r--p 0006e000 08:02 7606876                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
 7f14fc49b000-7f14fc49c000 rw-p 0006f000 08:02 7606876                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
 7f14fc49c000-7f14fc574000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606787                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
 7f14fc574000-7f14fc773000 ---p 000d8000 08:02 7606787                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
 7f14fc773000-7f14fc774000 r--p 000d7000 08:02 7606787                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
 7f14fc774000-7f14fc77c000 rw-p 000d8000 08:02 7606787                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
 7f14fc77c000-7f14fc77d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fc77d000-7f14fc79e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606814                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
 7f14fc79e000-7f14fc99d000 ---p 00021000 08:02 7606814                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
 7f14fc99d000-7f14fc99e000 r--p 00020000 08:02 7606814                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
 7f14fc99e000-7f14fc99f000 rw-p 00021000 08:02 7606814                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
 7f14fc99f000-7f14fc9be000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606905                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
 7f14fc9be000-7f14fcbbd000 ---p 0001f000 08:02 7606905                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
 7f14fcbbd000-7f14fcbbe000 r--p 0001e000 08:02 7606905                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
 7f14fcbbe000-7f14fcbbf000 rw-p 0001f000 08:02 7606905                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
 7f14fcbbf000-7f14fcbc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fcbc1000-7f14fcbd9000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606893                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
 7f14fcbd9000-7f14fcdd8000 ---p 00018000 08:02 7606893                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
 7f14fcdd8000-7f14fcdd9000 r--p 00017000 08:02 7606893                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
 7f14fcdd9000-7f14fcdda000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 7606893                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
 7f14fcdda000-7f14fcdde000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fcdde000-7f14fcf9e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606747                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7f14fcf9e000-7f14fd19e000 ---p 001c0000 08:02 7606747                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7f14fd19e000-7f14fd1a2000 r--p 001c0000 08:02 7606747                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7f14fd1a2000-7f14fd1a4000 rw-p 001c4000 08:02 7606747                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7f14fd1a4000-7f14fd1a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fd1a8000-7f14fd1af000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606901                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
 7f14fd1af000-7f14fd3ae000 ---p 00007000 08:02 7606901                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
 7f14fd3ae000-7f14fd3af000 r--p 00006000 08:02 7606901                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
 7f14fd3af000-7f14fd3b0000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 7606901                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
 7f14fd3b0000-7f14fd3fa000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606763                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
 7f14fd3fa000-7f14fd5fa000 ---p 0004a000 08:02 7606763                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
 7f14fd5fa000-7f14fd5fb000 r--p 0004a000 08:02 7606763                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
 7f14fd5fb000-7f14fd5fc000 rw-p 0004b000 08:02 7606763                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
 7f14fd5fc000-7f14fd604000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606833                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
 7f14fd604000-7f14fd804000 ---p 00008000 08:02 7606833                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
 7f14fd804000-7f14fd805000 r--p 00008000 08:02 7606833                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
 7f14fd805000-7f14fd806000 rw-p 00009000 08:02 7606833                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
 7f14fd806000-7f14fd81d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606835                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1.0.0
 7f14fd81d000-7f14fda1d000 ---p 00017000 08:02 7606835                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1.0.0
 7f14fda1d000-7f14fda1e000 r--p 00017000 08:02 7606835                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1.0.0
 7f14fda1e000-7f14fda1f000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 7606835                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1.0.0
 7f14fda1f000-7f14fda40000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606752                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
 7f14fda40000-7f14fdc3f000 ---p 00021000 08:02 7606752                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
 7f14fdc3f000-7f14fdc41000 r--p 00020000 08:02 7606752                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
 7f14fdc41000-7f14fdc42000 rw-p 00022000 08:02 7606752                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
 7f14fdc42000-7f14fdc4c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606806                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2.0.0
 7f14fdc4c000-7f14fde4b000 ---p 0000a000 08:02 7606806                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2.0.0
 7f14fde4b000-7f14fde4c000 r--p 00009000 08:02 7606806                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2.0.0
 7f14fde4c000-7f14fde4d000 rw-p 0000a000 08:02 7606806                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2.0.0
 7f14fde4d000-7f14fde73000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606719                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
 7f14fdfc6000-7f14fdfcc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fdfcc000-7f14fe04c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 7606915                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.14.0
 7f14fe04c000-7f14fe04f000 r--p 0007f000 08:02 7606915                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.14.0
 7f14fe04f000-7f14fe050000 rw-p 00082000 08:02 7606915                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.14.0
 7f14fe050000-7f14fe054000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fe069000-7f14fe070000 r--s 00000000 08:02 12061868                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
 7f14fe070000-7f14fe072000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f14fe072000-7f14fe073000 r--p 00025000 08:02 7606719                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
 7f14fe073000-7f14fe074000 rw-p 00026000 08:02 7606719                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
 7f14fe074000-7f14fe075000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7ffc34934000-7ffc34955000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
 7ffc34996000-7ffc34998000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
 7ffc34998000-7ffc3499a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
 ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
ProcStatus:
 Name:  upstart
 Umask: 0002
 State: S (sleeping)
 Tgid:  30642
 Ngid:  0
 Pid:   30642
 PPid:  30511
 TracerPid: 0
 Uid:   1000    1000    1000    1000
 Gid:   1000    1000    1000    1000
 FDSize:    256
 Groups:    4 24 27 30 46 113 128 1000 
 NStgid:    30642
 NSpid: 30642
 NSpgid:    30642
 NSsid: 30642
 VmPeak:       53548 kB
 VmSize:       53548 kB
 VmLck:        0 kB
 VmPin:        0 kB
 VmHWM:     4700 kB
 VmRSS:     4700 kB
 RssAnon:       1168 kB
 RssFile:       3532 kB
 RssShmem:         0 kB
 VmData:        1152 kB
 VmStk:      132 kB
 VmExe:      284 kB
 VmLib:     5032 kB
 VmPTE:      116 kB
 VmPMD:       12 kB
 VmSwap:           0 kB
 HugetlbPages:         0 kB
 Threads:   1
 SigQ:  27/30540
 SigPnd:    0000000000000000
 ShdPnd:    0000000000000000
 SigBlk:    0000000000000000
 SigIgn:    0000000000001000
 SigCgt:    0000000180016001
 CapInh:    0000000000000000
 CapPrm:    0000000000000000
 CapEff:    0000000000000000
 CapBnd:    0000003fffffffff
 CapAmb:    0000000000000000
 NoNewPrivs:    0
 Seccomp:   0
 Cpus_allowed:  f
 Cpus_allowed_list: 0-3
 Mems_allowed:  00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
 Mems_allowed_list: 0
 voluntary_ctxt_switches:   8613
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    1285
Signal: 6
Uname: Linux 4.10.0-35-generic x86_64
UserGroups: adm cdrom dip lpadmin plugdev sambashare sudo
_LogindSession: c6
```

#### Output of `lowriter`

```
    ** (soffice:6170): WARNING **: Unknown event notification 36
    ** (soffice:6170): WARNING **: Unknown event notification 36
    … … …
    ** (soffice:6170): WARNING **: Unknown event notification 36
    X IO Error
```

#### Content of ~/.xsession-errors

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

#### Content of /var/log/dmesg

```
    (Nothing has been logged yet.)
```

#### Content of /var/log/syslog

```
Oct  3 11:45:40 buster systemd[1]: Starting Automatically fetch and run repair assertions...
Oct  3 11:45:40 buster snap-repair[6937]: error: cannot use snap-repair on a classic system
Oct  3 11:45:40 buster systemd[1]: Started Automatically fetch and run repair assertions.
Oct  3 11:46:03 buster kernel: [ 6030.040353] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0x85dffffb, in Xorg [951], reason: Hang on render ring, action: reset
Oct  3 11:46:03 buster kernel: [ 6030.040390] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
Oct  3 11:46:03 buster kernel: [ 6030.040490] [drm] RC6 on
Oct  3 11:46:03 buster kernel: [ 6030.061093] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
Oct  3 11:46:16 buster kernel: [ 6042.959539] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
Oct  3 11:46:16 buster kernel: [ 6042.959607] [drm] RC6 on
Oct  3 11:46:16 buster kernel: [ 6042.973815] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
Oct  3 11:46:30 buster kernel: [ 6056.975691] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
Oct  3 11:46:30 buster kernel: [ 6056.975768] [drm] RC6 on
Oct  3 11:46:30 buster kernel: [ 6056.991880] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
Oct  3 11:46:45 buster kernel: [ 6071.983819] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
Oct  3 11:46:45 buster kernel: [ 6071.983890] [drm] RC6 on
Oct  3 11:46:45 buster kernel: [ 6071.998038] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster kernel: [ 6081.967887] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster kernel: [ 6081.967948] [drm] RC6 on
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster kernel: [ 6081.982176] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster org.gnome.Terminal[1320]: (gnome-terminal-server:6126): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster gnome-session[1456]: (update-notifier:2209): Gdk-WARNING **: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster org.freedesktop.Notifications[1320]: (notify-osd:2287): Gdk-WARNING **: notify-osd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster gnome-session[1456]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:1622): Gdk-WARNING **: polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1466]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1466]:       after 17781 requests (17781 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster gnome-session[1456]: (unity-fallback-mount-helper:1623): Gdk-WARNING **: unity-fallback-mount-helper: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster gnome-session[1456]: (gnome-software:1631): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-software: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster gnome-session[1456]: (nautilus:1632): Gdk-WARNING **: nautilus: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct  3 11:46:55 buster gnome-session[1456]: (nm-applet:1626): Gdk-WARNING **: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Oct  3 11:46:57 buster gnome-session[1456]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Oct  3 11:46:57 buster gnome-session[1456]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Oct  3 11:46:57 buster gnome-session[1456]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:7014): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
Oct  3 11:46:57 buster gnome-session[1456]: (deja-dup-monitor:3130): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Oct  3 11:46:57 buster gnome-session[1456]: (deja-dup-monitor:3130): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
Oct  3 11:46:57 buster gnome-session[1456]: gnome-session-binary[1456]: GLib-GIO-WARNING: Error releasing name org.gnome.SessionManager: The connection is closed
Oct  3 11:46:57 buster gnome-session-binary[1456]: GLib-GIO-WARNING: Error releasing name org.gnome.SessionManager: The connection is closed
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <info>  [1507020418.1059] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'connection-removed') [100 110 38]
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <info>  [1507020418.1066] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <info>  [1507020418.1138] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'connection-removed') [110 30 38]
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster avahi-daemon[744]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::bbe:3dc9:1304:7008 on wlp2s0.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster avahi-daemon[744]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::bbe:3dc9:1304:7008.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster avahi-daemon[744]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster lightdm[916]: ** (lightdm:916): CRITICAL **: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1234]: Stopped target Default.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1234]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1234]: Starting Exit the Session...
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1234]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1234]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1234]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1234]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <info>  [1507020418.1503] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2203
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <info>  [1507020418.1504] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1234]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 7065 (kill).
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster kernel: [ 6084.277192] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 74:da:38:14:12:d7 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster whoopsie[2066]: [11:46:58] offline
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster wpa_supplicant[976]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=74:da:38:14:12:d7 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster avahi-daemon[744]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.0.8 on wlp2s0.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster avahi-daemon[744]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.8.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <info>  [1507020418.1695] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster avahi-daemon[744]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster dnsmasq[2221]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of lightdm.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of adva.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 108...
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <info>  [1507020418.1902] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster dbus[798]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <warn>  [1507020418.2000] sup-iface[0x1c9ab80,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster NetworkManager[829]: <info>  [1507020418.2023] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user lightdm.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster dbus[798]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[7077]: Reached target Paths.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[7077]: Reached target Sockets.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[7077]: Reached target Timers.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[7077]: Reached target Basic System.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[7077]: Reached target Default.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[7077]: Startup finished in 28ms.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 108.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster org.a11y.atspi.Registry[7114]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Successfully made thread 7193 of process 7193 (n/a) owned by '108' high priority at nice level -11.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Successfully made thread 7219 of process 7193 (n/a) owned by '108' RT at priority 5.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Successfully made thread 7221 of process 7193 (n/a) owned by '108' RT at priority 5.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.140 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.140 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster pulseaudio[7193]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Successfully made thread 7223 of process 7223 (n/a) owned by '108' high priority at nice level -11.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster rtkit-daemon[1084]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Oct  3 11:46:58 buster pulseaudio[7223]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

Comment: Please start LibreOffice using a terminal with e.g. `lowriter`, wait for the crash to occur and [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/961370/edit) the terminal output to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response Owen, but that's not going to work because Unity (or whatever the windowing system is called these days) crashes and when the login prompt comes back the terminal window will be gone.

Comment: OK, then use `lowriter &>logfile` and post the content of the `logfile` file located in the directory where you run the command. Did you already try reinstalling with `sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice`?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/961370/edit) and add these log files directly after a crash: `~/.xsession-errors`, `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: [logfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By18jQkxAaOUUDNFWlpKMVl1V1k/view?usp=sharing)
[.xsession-errors](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By18jQkxAaOUMDNmVUtHYmxzWnc/view?usp=sharing)
[/var/log/dmesg] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By18jQkxAaOURmxPN2w1V2ZyRFU/view?usp=sharing)
[var/log/syslog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By18jQkxAaOUYWVFSWRKWU12bjA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've tried to reinstall now. Will report if crash still happens.

Comment: Crash happen even after reinstall.

Comment: Then please provide the log files I asked for [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961370/libreoffice-5-1-writer-crashes-after-sporadically-after-highlighting?noredirect=1#comment1537103_961370).

Comment: I did. https://askubuntu.com/questions/961370/libreoffice-5-1-writer-crashes-after-sporadically-after-highlighting?noredirect=1#comment1537150_961370

Comment: Please provide them [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/961370/edit) using code block (`{}` button).

Comment: OK, done. Had to cut the end of syslog because question too long. Rest is still at [syslog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By18jQkxAaOUYWVFSWRKWU12bjA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried to reset your LibreOffice user profile? https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile

Comment: Maybe the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/796095/in-16-04-libreoffice-crashes-my-os Please try what's suggested there.

Comment: dessert: OpenGL already disabled. xserver-xorg-video-intel already installed so that's not helpful.

Comment: mook765: tried your suggestion. Still crashes.

Comment: Suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1575301

A workaround is [to run libreoffice with `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95062#c11) environment variable. Changing this to the desktop startup icons:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
sudo perl -i.orig -p -e 's/Exec=libreoffice/Exec=env LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 libreoffice/g' libreoffice-*.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks Lari! Tried it, will report later if this fixed it.